# No se crean mis tablas en spring, hibernate y jpa

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Estoy con spring, hibernate y jpa. Tengo definido mis modelos y mi configuración de la siguiente manera:

```
server.port=8000
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/facturacion2?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

Ese es el properties. Luego defino una entidad producto con sus diferentes atributos:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Table(name="product")
@Entity
public class ProductEntity {
    
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="PRICE")
    private double price;
    @Column(name="PRICETOTAL")
    private double priceTotal;
    @Column(name="TAX")
    private double tax;
    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
    @Column(name="STOCK")
    private int stock;
    ...}
```

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial y veo que a el se le crean las tablas cada vez que compila pero a mi no. Bueno en todo caso yo ya tenia una base de datos realizada. Si junto la aplicacion a mi base de datos, no importa que ya haya creado mis tablas?

Comment: Si utilizas `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` crea el esquema y limpia los datos anteriores si existen.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez el tutorial que estas siguiendo esta utilizando la Base de datos H2 por lo tanto al utilizar la una base de datos como MYSQL no se va "crear" las tablas al compilar.
Lo que puedes revisar es que tengas agregado la dependencia del driver JDBC de MYSQL. Además, revisa la conexión de tu base de datos.

Tu archivo de conexión de **application.properties**:

```
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.xx.xx:3306/facturacion2
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

El driver de MYSQL en tu archivo pom:

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Puedes consultar el siguiente tutorial
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Pienso que tu conexión es incorrecta a tu base de datos.